# R Count values in DF variable by groups

Tags: r, count

Using following dataset:

```
set.seed(2)
origin <- rep(c("DEU", "GBR", "ITA", "NLD", "CAN", "MEX", "USA", "CHN", "JPN", "KOR","DEU", "GBR", "ITA", "NLD", "CAN", "MEX", "USA", "CHN", "JPN", "KOR"), 4)
year <- rep(c(rep(1998, 10), rep(2000, 10)), 2)
type <- sample(1:10, size=length(origin), replace=TRUE)
value <- sample(100:10000, size=length(origin), replace=TRUE)
test.df <- as.data.frame(cbind(origin, year, type, value))
rm(origin, year, type, value)
### add some (6) missing values
test.df$value[sample(1:length(test.df$value), 6, replace = FALSE)] <- NA
```

I want to count how many `type`s by country (`origin`) per `year`

I tryed:

```
count(trade.df, origin, year)
```

and

```
test.df %>% group_by(origin, year) %>% count()
```

but I am not sure of how I can interpret these results.

of course, if `value == NA`, R should not count it...

Comment: `with(test.df, table(origin, type, year))`? You can read `?table` for treatment of NAs

Comment: no, the result should be a 3 columns table, with origin, year, and the number of occurences

Comment: Okay, fyi there's `data.frame(with(test.df, table(origin, type, year)))` and with dplyr, I guess `test.df %>% count(origin, year, type, wt = !is.na(value))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the rows where `value` is `NA`, use `filter`:

```
test.df %>% group_by(origin,year) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>% count()

# A tibble: 20 x 3
# Groups:   origin, year [20]
   origin year      n
   <fct>  <fct> <int>
 1 CAN    1998      4
 2 CAN    2000      3
 3 CHN    1998      3
 4 CHN    2000      4
 5 DEU    1998      4
 6 DEU    2000      4
 7 GBR    1998      4
 8 GBR    2000      4
 9 ITA    1998      3
10 ITA    2000      4
11 JPN    1998      3
12 JPN    2000      3
13 KOR    1998      4
14 KOR    2000      4
15 MEX    1998      4
16 MEX    2000      4
17 NLD    1998      3
18 NLD    2000      4
19 USA    1998      4
20 USA    2000      4
```

Note, however, that this doesn't count how many `type`s there are in each group, but how many rows there are. If you want to count the number of unique `type`s, you can do this:

```
test.df %>% group_by(origin,year) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>% 
  summarize(n_distinct(type)) #Merci, @Frank!

# A tibble: 20 x 3
# Groups:   origin [?]
   origin year  `length(unique(type))`
   <fct>  <fct>                  <int>
 1 CAN    1998                       3
 2 CAN    2000                       3
 3 CHN    1998                       2
 4 CHN    2000                       3
 5 DEU    1998                       4
 6 DEU    2000                       3
 7 GBR    1998                       4
 8 GBR    2000                       4
 9 ITA    1998                       3
10 ITA    2000                       4
11 JPN    1998                       3
12 JPN    2000                       2
13 KOR    1998                       4
14 KOR    2000                       4
15 MEX    1998                       3
16 MEX    2000                       3
17 NLD    1998                       2
18 NLD    2000                       3
19 USA    1998                       3
20 USA    2000                       4
```

Comment: Or `drop_na(value)` instead of `filter(!is.na(value))` if `tidyr` is loaded.

Comment: Thanks Frank - I forgot about that one.